# Ampscript to update status using SFID as Subscriber Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are using a custom unsub link and we are now migrating all records to use SFID as subscriber key.

I need to update this code so that it can update both records in list, Email one and SFID one. Currently it is working with email but throw error when we send email by setting “SFID as subscriberkey” in send relationship.

Here are the Subscriber records:

```
piyush @gmail.com(Email) piyush@gmail.com(subscriberkey)
piyush@gmail.com(Email)  0036F00002vYwAzQAK(subscriberkey)
```

Here is the code:

```
%%[

VAR @sid, @jid, @reason, @lue, @lue_prop, @lue_statusCode, @overallStatus, @requestId, @Response, @Status, @Error, @mid, @Email, @EmailName, @MessageHeader, @MessageBody

SET @mid = [memberid]
SET @sid = [emailaddr]
SET @jid = [jobid]
SET @listid = [listid]
SET @batchid = [_JobSubscriberBatchID]
SET @Email = [emailaddr]
SET @EmailName = [emailname_]
SET @reason = "Custom One Click Unsubscribe"

SET @MessageHeader = "Thank you!"
SET @MessageBody = "You have been unsubscribed from this publication."

IF NOT EMPTY(@Email) THEN

    /*Insert into Log DE*/
    InsertDE("Unsub_Log","SubscriberKey",@sid,"Email",@Email,"UnsubEmail",@EmailName,"UnsubDateLocal",SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()),"UnsubDateSystem",Now())


    /*Start Log Unsub Event*/
    SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")                 
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @sid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

    SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)


    var @lue_oyb 
    set @lue_oyb = CreateObject('ClientID') 
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_oyb, 'ID', @mid) 
    SetObjectProperty(@lue, 'Client', @lue_oyb)


    SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

    SET @UTC_Date = DateAdd(Now(), "6", "H") 

    /*Update DataExtension2 DE*/
    UpdateDE("DataExtension2",1,"Email",@Email,"MARKETING_OPTIN","False")
    UpdateDE("DataExtension2",1,"Email",@Email,"CONTACTABLE_VIA_EMAIL","False")
    UpdateDE("DataExtension2",1,"Email",@Email,"UTC_DATE_LAST_MODIFIED",@UTC_Date)
    UpdateDE("DataExtension2",1,"Email",@Email,"SFMC_DATE_LAST_MODIFIED",Now())

    /*Update DataExtension3 DE*/
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"MARKETING_OPTIN","False")
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"MARKETING_OPTIN_LAST_MODIFIED",Now())
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"MARKETING_OPTIN_DATE",Null)
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"MARKETING_OPTOUT_DATE",Now())
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"CONTACTABLE_VIA_EMAIL","False")
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"CONTACTABLE_VIA_EMAIL_LAST_MODIFIED",Now())
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"EMAIL_NON_CONTACTABLE_REASON","Unsubscribed")
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"EMAIL_UNSUBSCRIBED","True")
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"EMAIL_UNSUBSCRIBED_DATE",Now())
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"EMAIL_UNSUBSCRIBED_NAME",@EmailName)
    UpdateDE("DataExtension3",1,"Email",@Email,"SFMC_DATE_LAST_MODIFIED",Now())


ENDIF   

SET @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
SET @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
SET @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode") 

IF @overallStatus != "OK" AND @Error != 12012 AND @Error != 401 THEN

    SET @MessageHeader = "Sorry!"
    SET @MessageBody = "Something went wrong and we could not process your request. Please try again later"

ENDIF

]%%
```

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried changing `SET @sid = [emailaddr]` to `SET @sid = _subscriberkey`?

Comment: Hi ..Yes [SET @sid = _subscriberkey] is working but only one way. I need to unsubscribe both records, Email and SFID - as subscriber key